# Unable to setup the drizzle vue plugin with the vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, truffle, drizzle

I have setup the drizzle with vuejs 2 using official documentation [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/blob/develop/packages/vue-plugin/README.md).

When I try running the project with `yarn serve` I am getting the following errors

[image]

For the fix, I tried installing all the packages. Unfortunately it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is pretty simple.

1. Install the packages

   ```
   yarn add -D buffer process stream-browserify os-browserify stream-http https-browserify url
   ```
2. Configure the webpack in the vue.config.js file

   ```js
   resolve: {
    fallback: {
      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
      url: require.resolve("url"),
      assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    },
   },
   ```
3. Start the vuejs dev server

   ```
   yarn serve
   ```